# BindingList on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, bindinglist

Is BindingList part of the .NET framework for Windows Phone 8? I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and it cannot find the class. I am using the `System.ComponentModel` namespace where it should be located, but visual studio gives me errors saying "The type or namespace name 'BindingList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I have searched extensively on the internet and I cannot find any other records of a similar issue.

The reason I would like to use a BindingList is because I have a ListBox which uses a List as its datasource, and when an object is added or removed from the ListBox, the list displayed on the screen doesn't update automatically. According to my research on Google, using a BindingList instead of a List should solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: If `BindingList` is unavaliable you could use `ObservableCollection` instead, this will also update the `Listbox` when changes are made

Comment: This workaround worked well. Thank you.

Comment: Adding to sa_ddam213's answer: BindingList is meant to be used with WinForms. ObservableCollection's are meant to be used with XAML based databinding.